# Where to find ip.h file on ubuntu server?

Tags: 22.04, users, raspberrypi, ip

I am using ubuntu server 22.04.1 LTS on raspberry pi 4. I want to know where ip.h file is located inside it. And where would I find the source codes for traceroute and ifconfig on the ubuntu server as well?

Thanks!
Divya

Comment: What is this `ip.h` supposed to be? There may or may not be header files installed depending on what packages you have installed. There is a [`/usr/include/netinet/ip.h` provided by `libc6-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&mode=exactfilename&arch=any&suite=focal&keywords=ip.h)

Comment: ip.h contains the source code of the ip header

Comment: I was able to locate /usr/include. But there doesn't seem to be the folder netinet

Comment: As I said, which header files you have in your system depends on which packages you have installed. So first it's important to clarify *which* `ip.h` you're looking for. There are many: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&mode=exactfilename&arch=any&suite=focal&keywords=ip.h

Comment: Okay, that gave me some clarity. Thanks!